# Avoid MongoDB to load index

Tags: mongodb

I want to perform a huge query that performs joins across my database, more than 600 collections with billions of documents. The point is that if I perform that query, my db will explode because MongoDB will be trying to load the index of each collection.

¿Is there any way to avoid MongoDB to automatically load the indexes of each collection?

Comment: Unless you are loading the full data for each collection, this seems a case where you'd definitely want indexes to be used so MongoDB can be efficient about finding and loading relevant documents. You have the option of [forcing a collection scan](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/#force-collection-scans) using a cursor hint on the `$natural` index, but I suspect that isn't what you want to do. How many collections are you actually trying to join in your query?

Comment: A better question to ask might be how to efficiently structure your data for querying (including an example document, query, and desired output). If you commonly need to do a large number of joins (or joins across a number of large collections) this is a strong hint that your data model could likely be adjusted to better support your application use case.

Comment: I want to query more than 700 collections with more than 150 million documents each. Loading the indexes of that amount of collections cause an OOM error, so that's why I want to force Mongo to avoid loading them. This query is a special case that will be performed rarely, so I don't want to change the structure of the collections.